# How to check if html contains a certain number with iMacros

Tags: html, if-statement, screen-scraping, imacros, data-extraction

I would like to use iMacros to check a html site if it contains certain numbers. if it does, then I would like to assign a variable according to a number that has been found.

Like if the html contains 112233 then I woul like to assing Var1 to be 123
if the html contains 223344 then I want Var1 to be 645

What would be the way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow! That is a typical case for [iMacros EVAL](http://wiki.imacros.net/EVAL)!

Extract the element's text with TAG and assign the value to !VAR1, using EVAL for the conditional.

If the text is not inside an html element (it could be in a comment, for instance) and so, not reachable by the TAG command, sou can try with [SEARCH](http://wiki.imacros.net/SEARCH), which does offer some regular expression facility as well.